# How do I define a method that can accept 2 arguments but can function with just 1, with a default value for the other?

Tags: ruby

short example.

```
def yay(a, b = "1")
value  = a + b
return value
end
```

I would like to be able to do this

```
something.yay(2)
```

and get 3 returned, and also do this

```
something.yay(2,3)
```

and get 5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did the trick yourself already. Just change the default value to `1` (w/out quotes) or call `value  = a + b.to_i`.

Comment: take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710303/rails-optional-argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have it right, the only problem I suppose is the data type.

Try:

```
def yay(a, b = 1)
  a + b
end
```

Or if this method is to operate only on integer types you could cast both parameters to integer using `to_i` as:

```
def yay(a, b = "1")
  a.to_i + b.to_i
end
```

Comment: `return` is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Fixnum` literal, instead of string literal:

```
class Something
  def yay(a, b = 1) # <----
    a + b # You don't need `return`: the last value evaluated is returned.
  end
end
something = Something.new
something.yay(2)
# => 3
something.yay(2, 3)
# => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following useful for general purpose of this sort:

```
def foo(*a)
  ## define default vals
  params = {'param1_name' => 'def_val_1','param2_name' => 
'def_val_2','param3_name' => 'def_val_3'}
  params.each_with_index do |(key_,val_), ind_|
    params[key_] = ( a.first[ind_].nil? ? val_ : a.first[ind_])
    puts params[key_]
  end

end
```

### when calling function put nil if you desire a default val

```
foo (['path' ,nil, 'path3' ])
=>
path
def_val_2
path3
```