# rails helper method required parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've read this thread: [Rails optional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710303/rails-optional-argument) and tried to implement it in a Rails 4 helper function that looks like this:

```
# this is in the application helper
def getRank(team_id, week = '')
  if week.empty?
    week = Settings.pluck(:week) # grab the current week
  end
  # do some stuff to get the current team's rank
end
```

When I call this in the console however I still get:

```
> helper.getRank(5)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
from /home/rails_testing/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:24:in `getRank'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you do have something after week = that is not a comment, right?

Comment: @nPn it is `week = ''` -- the same as in the example I quoted.

Comment: i mean the week = # grap the current week

Comment: oh sure. I just commented the DB / model stuff to save typing.

Comment: I think you need to show more of what you really have, I just added this to my ApplicationHelper (changed week = # grap to week = 3 #grap to get past the syntax error) and the did helper.getRank(5) and did not get any error

Comment: Did you restart your `rails console` after changing that helper method?

Comment: are you sure the error is not in Setting.pluck(:week) needing 2 arguments?  ... what is on line 24 ?

Comment: @spickermann-- d'oh. that was it. thanks for the ideas nPn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rails console` reads your application code when it is started. Therefore you need to restart your `rails console` after changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You must restart your `rails console` every time you make changes in your code.

You can restart console with this `reload!` command.