# The Well Grounded Rubyist - Syntax Question - Optional Argument or Hash Argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm currently going through "The Well Grounded Rubyist 2nd Edition" I'm on page 296 and have been given the following code

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(options)
    self.age = options[:age]
  end

  def teenager?
    (13..19) === age
  end
end
```

what does `options[:age]` refer to?
is it an optional argument or something?
If I were writing that class, I would have written that line like `@age = options`

Edit - I forgot to mention, I did find this question - [Rails optional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710303/rails-optional-argument) - that uses the line used in the book. But i couldn't work out why it was used or why `options` was used with the symbol `[:age]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options` isn't an optional argument, because initializing a Person object without that argument would throw an `ArgumentError` error, because it's expecting one argument but you passed no argument:

```
Person.new
# file.rb:4:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

In that case `options` is meant to be a hash or any object that responds to the method `[]`. So, if you initialize a Person object with hash containing the symbol key `age`, then `self.age` will take that value:

```
p Person.new(age: 100)
# <Person:0x00007ff05b84eab0 @age=100>
```

The use of hash as arguments gives you a flexibility at the moment of invoking a method, because you can wrap any needed object into the hash, you just need to take care of handling them in the method definition.

If you do `self.age = options` (or `@age = options`), then you're assigning to `self.age` the whole options object, which can be the whole hash or anything passed as the argument:

```
def initialize(options)
  self.age = options
end
...

p Person.new(age: 100, another_thing: nil)
# #<Person:0x00007ff47e09aa18 @age={:age=>100, :another_thing=>nil}>
```

Comment: ah I see. the book does use  ```people = 10.step(25,3).map {|i| Person.new(age: i) }``` in order to instantiate multiple Person

Comment: There you can see that options is a hash like `{ age: i }`.

Comment: @Sebatian One thought, at what point is the options hash created?

Comment: The hash is the parameter you're using when invoking the method. Ruby allows you to omit the `{}` when the last (or only one) argument is a hash. So `Person.new({age: 100})` is pretty much the same as `Person.new(age: 100)`.